# Listview ForeColor per item

Tags: c#, oracle, listview, colors

This application is a message board type of app.  You post a message, which is stored in an Oracle database.  The user's photo, name, date and message are displayed in a listview.  Everything works however a feature request for font color changing came in.  Now testing things below I know I can display ALL of the messages as a certain color.

What I'm going to do is add a 'color' column to my table.  Then if a user selects the text of their message to be 'red' for example, I am going to store the hex color for red in the color column of the table for that post.

So what I'm trying to figure out is when that message is retrieved, how I can set this code to 'If color column empty, post message as black, else if hex color exist for each message post that particular message in that color' Without changing the color of every message to red as the code below currently does.

```
        List<MsgBoard> Messages = MsgBoard.find_ActiveByBoardName(Convert.ToString(cmbgroup.SelectedItem));
        int i = 0;
        imageList1.Images.Clear();

        foreach (MsgBoard m in Messages)
        {
            AddImages(m.EmpPic);

            ListViewItem Message = new ListViewItem("", i);
            if (m.AlertNo == 0) //Default Message Post (non Alert)
            {
                Message.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
                Message.SubItems.Add(m.EmpName.First);
                Message.SubItems.Add(m.MessageText + Environment.NewLine).ForeColor = Color.Red;
                Message.SubItems.Add(m.PostDate.ToString());
                Message.SubItems.Add(m.EmpName.EmpNo.ToString());
                Message.SubItems.Add(m.EmpName.Name);
                listView1.Items.Add(Message);                
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Just to clarify.  If 20 people post a message and all 20 select a different color to post their message in.  So in the DB all 20 rows have a different color in the DB column, I need to have those messages displayed in listview individually based on the color they posted as.  I currently am only aware of applying a single color to all messages in listview as shown in my example above.

Looks like thanks to Stephan, once I add

`Message.SubItems.Add(m.MessageText + Environment.NewLine).ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(m.Color);`

I then need help adjusting my query to add the color once colors are added to the color column.  Here is that code.

Had DB admin add MESSAGE_COLOR varchar column.

I edit this below to existing code, for the newly created column MESSAGE_COLOR when posting..

```
    public string Create()
    {
        try
        {
            OleDbDataReader result = Database.Conn.Execute(
                "INSERT INTO MPCS.MEYER_BOARD (" +
                "EMPLOYEE_ID, " +
                "POST_DATE, " +
                "BOARD_NAME," +
                "ALERT_NO," +
                "MESSAGE_TEXT," +
                "MESSAGE_COLOR," +
                "ACTIVE_FLAG" +
                ") VALUES (?,SYSDATE,?,?,?,?)",
                new List<OleDbParameter> {
                     new OleDbParameter("EMPLOYEE_ID",EmpName.EmpNo),
                     new OleDbParameter("BOARD_NAME",BoardName),
                     new OleDbParameter("ALERT_NO",AlertNo),
                     new OleDbParameter("MESSAGE_TEXT",MessageText),
                     new OleDbParameter("MESSAGE_COLOR",MessageColor),
                     new OleDbParameter("ACTIVE_FLAG",ActiveFlag ? "Y" : "N")
                    }, Query.ReaderType.Reader);
            result.Read();
            result.Close();
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

I then editing DB read w/ the new column as well.

```
public static MsgBoard DBRead(OleDbDataReader result,string alias=null)
    {
        return new MsgBoard
        {
            EmpName = Employee.DBRead(result, "EMPLOYEE"),
            MessageText = result[alias + "MESSAGE_TEXT"].ToString(),
            MessageColor = result[alias + "MESSAGE_COLOR"].ToString(),
            BoardName = result[alias +"BOARD_NAME"].ToString(),
            AlertNo = (int)(decimal)result[alias +"ALERT_NO"],
            PostDate = (DateTime)result[alias +"POST_DATE"],
            ActiveFlag = result[alias +"ACTIVE_FLAG"].ToString().ToString() == "Y",
            EmpPic = ImageResource.DBRead(result, "IR")
        };
    }
```

But do I need to edit my build_query?

```
    public static String build_query(String where, string OrderBy = null)
    {
        List<String> cols = new List<String>();
        cols.AddRange(db_columns.ConvertAll(c => "MPCS.MEYER_BOARD." + c + " AS MBOARD_" + c));
        cols.AddRange(Employee.db_columns.ConvertAll(c => "MPCS.EMPLOYEE." + c + " AS EMPLOYEE_" + c));
        cols.AddRange(ImageResource.db_columns.ConvertAll(c => "MPCS.IMAGE_RESOURCE." + c + " AS IR_" + c));
        String sql =
            "SELECT " + String.Join(", ", cols) + " " +
            "FROM MPCS.MEYER_BOARD " +
            "LEFT OUTER JOIN MPCS.EMPLOYEE " +
            "ON MPCS.MEYER_BOARD.EMPLOYEE_ID=MPCS.EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_ID " +
            "LEFT OUTER JOIN MPCS.IMAGE_RESOURCE " +
            "ON MPCS.IMAGE_RESOURCE.IR_ID=MPCS.EMPLOYEE.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID " +
        "WHERE ";
        sql += where;
        sql += OrderBy;
        return sql;
    }
```

**UPDATE**

I've gotten everything coded and I am submitting the color to the DB now.  However when displaying the listview below each post still just has a default black text color.  Rather than the color saved for example as "#FFF000" being converted and displayed.

```
foreach (MsgBoard m in Messages)
        {
            AddImages(m.EmpPic);

            ListViewItem Message = new ListViewItem("", i);
            if (m.AlertNo == 0) //Default Message Post (non Alert)
            {
                Message.SubItems.Add(m.EmpName.First);                   
                Message.SubItems.Add(m.MessageText + Environment.NewLine).ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(m.MessageColor);
                Message.SubItems.Add(m.PostDate.ToString());
                Message.SubItems.Add(m.EmpName.EmpNo.ToString());
                Message.SubItems.Add(m.EmpName.Name); //Displayed only on 'Show Details'
                listView1.Items.Add(Message);
            }
```

**Final update**

Turns out the last piece I was missing was to change the listview property `UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;` now its working.

Comment: So how do you access the stored color? if it is a `int` you can simply write `.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(yourIntValue)`.. And readin in a default value of `0` from the DBMS also shouldn't be a problem. Going via hex is an option but makes little sense unless somebody actually can read/understand/edit  them..

Comment: The person posting will never see the hex. The problem is not retreiving the color but have more than 1.  So if 20 people post a message that's potentially 20 different colors.  As per my example listview will post all messages to the set color.  I'm trying to figure out how to, based on the persons posted color, display each message in listview with their individual color rather than all messages one color like above.

Comment: No, each [ListViewItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) can have its own colors, both foreground and background. If you store the color with the messages it will work just fine.

Comment: Right... But I'm asking how.  Right now there is a good 90 messages in the table.  All black text currently as this is a new request.  So how, using my existing code can I edit this so that once it also looks at the newly added color column of the table it can start displaying each message w/ that corresponding color..

Comment: So is there a column wit the color? what's the name and type?

Comment: Edited everything above w/ what I've fixed (DB Creation, DB Read)  But do I need to edit my build_query?

Comment: Probably not. So is there really anything unclear now? You get the color for each message and you set it..

Comment: Ok so I've saved the hex "#fff000" for example color to the DB.  However text per post is still default black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your hex value (assuming that it is stored as a string in the format `"#RRGGBB"`) into a color using [`ColorTranslator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.drawing.colortranslator.fromhtml.aspx)
Using this approach, you can also use named colors (like `"Violet"`)

```
Message.SubItems.Add(m.MessageText + Environment.NewLine).ForeColor =  
    System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(m.Color); //sth. like "#FFCC66"
```

Furthermore you have to retrieve the value of the `Color` column. It seems that you have to add `"MESSAGE_COLOR"` (or whatever your column is called) to your `db_columns`. When you got the values from the DB, you have to map the column to the property of your `Message`:

```
return new MsgBoard
{
  // ...
  Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml([alias+"MESSAGE_COLOR"]),
  // ...
}
```

(In other words: You already save it to db, now you also have to read it from DB)

Comment: I know I can pull the color and convert.  That's fine.  I just haven't added that because my problem will still exist.  Once I retrieve the hex color save, and apply it as I have in my example, it will affect the color of everyone's message.  I'm trying to figure out how to apply it individually.  So if Bob post a message w/ blue text and Tim post a message with Red text, each persons post displayed in listview is the color they posted it as.

Comment: Ah ok. Could you please add this to your question because imho this wasn't really clear. :)

Comment: I added it, but it states "I know I can post ALL messages in one color" and ends with "Without changing the color of every message to red as the code below currently does."

Comment: Sure but it's obvious that everything is red if you set the color of every message to red. If I use above code, every message has a different color (if `m.Color` is different for each `m`)

Comment: I see, ok I need to add what you have, but primarily edit my database call in my class.  Let me grab that and post in above.

Comment: Ok so I've saved the hex "#fff000" for example color to the DB.  However text per post is still default black.